# Google Sheets Query formula, find and select X value from rows

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

[image]

Hello i want to auto-fill the  cell and fill with "The Tweety House" as that one is the highest "$ Result"(111.111), i dont know how to do that maybe someone here can help me to figure it out.

Thank you

Comment: Could you share an example sheet so the community can have a better understanding of what you are trying to do? It would be great if you can share as well what have you tried so far, remember to include a [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well.

Comment: thank you for the response, here the example [google sheets link](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1zY1BoYAPm5STu2irYn9edNGlDQ6vrhp3-fbaLpDpnkI/edit?usp=sharing) , O6 cell i type manually, i want the be auto-fill, based on Highest $ Result and following the slot name. Thank you once again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In O6 try

```
=+sort(B11:B, AJ11:AJ, 0)
```

Also removes the formulas in AE11:AE and enter in AE11

```
=INDEX(IF(AJ11:AJ<>"", AJ11:AJ/W11:W,))
```

Then for V6 you can use

```
=+sort(B11:B, AE11:AE, 0)
```

Note:

- for O5 you can use

  ```
  =MAX(AJ11:AJ)
  ```
- and for V5

  ```
  =MAX(AE11:AE)
  ```

See if that helps?

Comment: thank you for helping me sir, the O6 problem was solved nicely, but the V6 give me <blank> result. also i do "removes the formulas in AE11:AE and enter in AE11" with "=INDEX(IF(AJ11:AJ<>"", AJ11:AJ/W11:W,))" and give me #REF error

Comment: its worked now. thanks man!!! very appreciate, the "=INDEX(IF(AJ11:AJ<>"", AJ11:AJ/W11:W,))" give #ref error but i try remove "AJ and W" change to "=INDEX(IF(AJ11<>"", AJ11/W11,))" and its work nicely now, both(O6 and V6) cell give correct value.